# Docker: Running Celery in detatched -d mode

Tags: django, docker, celery

I'm not sure if I am missing something, or not quite understanding the nuances of containerization, but I have provisioned `celery` and `celery-beat` services that are working in attached mode, e.g., using:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up --build`

But the are not beating when used in detatched mode:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up --build -d`

The only output I can see is the following:

```
celery-beat_1  | celery beat v4.4.0 (cliffs) is starting.
celery-beat_1  | __    -    ... __   -        _
celery-beat_1  | LocalTime -> 2020-01-24 16:32:57
celery-beat_1  | Configuration ->
celery-beat_1  |     . broker -> redis://redis:6379/0
celery-beat_1  |     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
celery-beat_1  |     . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
celery-beat_1  |     . db -> celerybeat-schedule
celery-beat_1  |     . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
celery-beat_1  |     . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

Whereas the output I want is to contain the following:

```
celery-beat_1  | [2020-01-24 14:56:08,325: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
celery-beat_1  | <ScheduleEntry: Wave.celery.dispatch_surfers_waivers_periodic_task() Wave.celery.dispatch_surfers_waivers_periodic_task() <crontab: 6,16,26,36,46,56 * * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
```

I'm not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I've added some output I see, and some extra output I *want* to see...

Comment: Detached mode implies that your container will run in background. You can access its output by reattaching to the container by using `docker attach <container_pid>`

Comment: Issue was related to using an incorrect cront schedule, I had '0,15,30,45,60' which clearly is an issue.